# Removing all of empty characters in Python

Tags: python, string, file

I want to replace all of the empty characters with single empty character. I tried this:

```
import re

fin = open("toutput_des.txt", "r")
fout = open("toutput2_des.txt", "w")

for line in fin:
    fout.write(re.sub('\s+',' ',line))
    
fin.close()
fout.close()
```

It worked but it also replaced "new line" character at the end of each line with a single empty character. If I want to exclude the "new line" how can I modify regex?
I also tried '\s+\b' but it deleted all of the contents of the file.

Comment: If by "empty characters" you literally mean "spaces", then why not just `r' +'`?  `\s` by definition includes other white space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may simply append the newline back after replacing.

However, you do not need a regex here, you can use

```py
for line in fin:
    fout.write(' '.join(line.split()) + '\n')
```

Note that `line.split()` splits the string with any whitespace while removing leading and trailing whitespaces, and `' '.join(...)` joins the items back with a single space.

If you need to use a regex solution, then you can subtract `\n` from `\s`:

```py
re.sub(r'[^\S\n]+', ' ', line)
```

The `[^\S\n]+` regex matches any one or more chars other than non-whitespace and line feed char, i.e. it matches any whitespace chars but line feed chars.
You probably also want to `.lstrip()` the result.

Comment: This will return the wrong result if the last line didn't originally have a newline

Comment: @Francisco This is fine in Linux. Anyway, I posted the fixed regular expression.